# Configurable product price removed after assigning simple products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product, virtual-products

We have configurable products each with a price. These products are ordered by price on category pages.

When assigning simple products to an existing configurable product, the price of the configurable product is taken over by the simple products assigned to the configurable product. The price field on admin site is greyed out and can't be changed anymore.

The problem is that the order on category pages is still ordered by the price set on the configurable product and not by the prices of the simple products assigned to the configurable product.
+ when saving the configurable product again after it has simple products assigned to it, the price is removed of the configurable product. 
This means that the product is set on the first place on category pages because Magento only looks at the price of the configurable product which is 0 because it was removed after saving.

The only solution we find is to update the price of the configurable product with the bulk method and set it to a price of an assigned simple product.
But this is not a correct and fast way.

The image below show a configurable product with no price because it's removed after saving with simple products.
[image: Configurable product]

Information:
Magento ver. 2.3.1

Is it normal for Magento to only look at the prices of configurable product for the order on category pages and is there anyone who knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In M2.3.x the min_price of the configurable product should be used for the sorting. So the lowest price of any simple product.

There is a closed issue in magento github (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23180) which is also tested in m2.3.1. As a first step i would update to 2.3.5-p1 and recheck. The issue should be gone after indexing.

Comment: Updating the website to 2.3.5-p1 unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked on 2.3.5-p1 version, because I am using 2.3.5-p1 version still facing issue.
My issue on gihtub already logged https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28068

Comment: We have also updated the website to 2.3.5-p1 and the problem is still there.